# Why my Facebook's font corrupts on Chrome?

Tags: facebook, font

Facebook's font doesn't seem to display correctly on my Chrome browser, though it has no problem with Firefox and IE.

See the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of problem]

It has happened quite long ago but I still can't figure out how to solve this. What I have tried so far is replace the Facebook's font (lucida grande) but it doesn't allow me to override the existing one.

Remember that it only occurs on Chrome rather than all browsers.

Comment: Alex: did you edit my post? Sorry for using external link but as you see apparently, nobody can recognize the font problem with this embedded image, too small! Thanks.

Comment: Best to direct this bug to Facebook Support.

Comment: Is there any issue here, or are these posts just in a foreign language?